# Azure APIM: How does APIM in internal mode serve backend APIs for a web app?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to follow steps on this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c#configure-and-secure-the-function-api

It uses APIM to serve the backend APIs of a SPA web app.

In step 14 and 15, it says:

> 14. Open the API Management blade of the portal, then open your instance.
> 15. Record the Private VIP shown on the overview tab.

An APIM with a Private VIP must be in internal mode.

However, When I configure APIM to Internal mode, it's accessible only through its private IP within the Virtual Network. It is not accessible from the public internet, i guess?

Then, how is it possible to serve the backend APIs as the doc has suggested? The HTTP requests to the backend are coming from the public internet, as shown in the graph below in (3):

[image]

This graph is directly copied from the documentation

Did I got my basic facts wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The apim service will continue to have a public IP address to be used for the incoming management api requests (add, remove or update Apis, products etc.) and to be used for outgoing public requests.

See the [APIM document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet?tabs=stv2#routing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see it will still use a public IP address for incoming management API requests, but for normal backend requests sent by users or clients from the public Internet, how can the APIM still receive them ?  The graph from the documentation ( see my updated post ) suggests that the APIM module just receives the HTTP request from the clients from the Internet.

Comment: if the service is in internal vnet, then incoming gateway requests will only be accepted from either within the internal vnet or peered vnet/ om-prem network

Comment: for the outgoing requests, if thee re no vnet blockers (like nsg rule, custom routing etc..) then outgoing public and private requests to the backend are allowed